# Como obtener resultado de la autenticacion de un webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hola quisiera saber si es posible obtener el resultado de la autenticación de un webview, la web que abre consta de Usuario, Contraseña y captcha. por favor necesito una orientación, gracias.

he intentado de esta forma:

```
var http = new HttpClient();
var getRequest = "https://www.miweb.com";
var getResponse = await http.GetAsync(getRequest);
var getResult = await getResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Esta web lleva autenticacion y codigo captcha, cuando escribo el usuario la contraseña y el captcha ella abre, pero quisiera obtener por debajo si la autencacion fallo o fue satisfactoria. La web no posee api, solo estoy intentado replicarlo a un app android

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: y que has hecho para conseguirlo???

Comment: Disculpen por la falta, no tengo mucha experiencia, voy a poner lo que estoy intentando